# How can I remove text to the right from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Transactions.csv', usecols=[0, 1, 3])
KFC = df[df.Description.str.contains("KFC*")]
print(KFC)
```

I currently have this which is a transaction of my bank statements, I'm looking a specific fast food place, this is working fine but I'm having issues working out how to remove the string after KFC*

```
      Date        Description                                Debit
66    30/07/2020  KFC* - Visa Purchase - Receipt 178632I... -40.35
73    29/07/2020  KFC* - Visa Purchase - Receipt 197989I... -27.40
173   17/07/2020  KFC* - Visa Purchase - Receipt 118930I... -45.30
246    2/07/2020  KFC* - Visa Purchase - Receipt 11... -14.95
```

I've tried rstrip, strip but it doesn't seem to work when looking for a specific string.
What's the best way to go about getting it to look like this instead.

```
Date  Description       Debit
66    30/07/2020  KFC* -40.35
73    29/07/2020  KFC* -27.40
173   17/07/2020  KFC* -45.30
246    2/07/2020  KFC* -14.95
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways

Pandas `.str` accessor works with regex, so you can extract the pattern you look for and then delete the rows where the pattern was not found

```
KFC = df.copy()
KFC.Description = KFC.Description.str.extract('(KFC\*)')
KFC.dropna(subset=['Description'], inplace= True)
```

Second option: the substring 'KFC*' always appears at the start of the string then you are essentially just changing the whole column to 'KFC*'. Add to the end of your code

```
KFC.Description = 'KFC*'
```

Or even delete the column, it adds no information

Comment: the KFC.Description works fine for my purposes of learning.

Can you go into more detail with the first example?
As when I try to use that, I run into TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'Description' was passed

Comment: of course, it was missing the brackets around `['Description']` in the dropna line...try it now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function of the series to do this.

```py
KFC['Description'] = KFC['Description'].map(lambda x: x.split('-', 1)[0].strip())
```

This one should split by the first instance of `-` and take the first part, but honestly if you just want to set it for this specific case then you can simply set the text as

```py
KFC['Description'] = "KFC*"
```